# XxxxxPersistence null pointer @BeanReference annotation

Tags: spring, junit, nullpointerexception, annotations, liferay

I try to use the method public XxxxxLocalService getXxxxxLocalService() from xxxxxlocalServiceBaseImpl.java class which was generated by the service builder but I get a null value in the variable xxxxxLocalService!

```
public xxxxxLocalService getClientLocalService() {
return xxxxxLocalService;
}
```

this variable is instantiated by the @BeanReference annotation as we can see at the head of the java file:

```
@BeanReference(type = xxxxxLocalService.class)
protected XxxxxLocalService xxxxxLocalService;
@BeanReference(type = XxxxxPersistence.class)
protected XxxxxPersistence xxxxxPersistence;
```

the ServieBaseImpl package contains services with @BeanReference annotations that are processed by BeanReferenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor that uses one of BeanLocators.

I noticed that there is a chicken & egg problem. You cannot load these beans without BeanLocator that is already populated with application context containing @BeanReferenced beans.

But you cannot create application context for BeanLocator to be populated with, because if you do so and BeanReferenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor is part of the context, it will use BeanLocator that is not initialized.

BeanReferenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor is declared in base-spring.xml that needs to be loaded with other bean definitions (from portlet-spring.xml etc.), because they depend on each other.

I don't know why this class can't set the variable value? in fact I'm not using the base-spring.xml in my configuration .. so I'm asking which lines I have to add in my ressource file for being able to use the bean reference annotation!!
Thanks

Comment: ServiceBuilder typically instantiates the appropriate XxxxxLocalServiceImpl object for you - once that is done, you can also access its super class's members. How is the object constructed that you're calling this operation on?

Comment: Hi sir, you said "ServiceBuilder typically instantiates the appropriate XxxxxLocalServiceImpl object for you" ... I agree with you but this is possible if I'm using the  @BeanReference annotation ... but in my code I didn't add any lines to solve this probleme...  for example the  base-spring.xml contains this declaration
 <bean class="com.liferay.portal.kernel.spring.util.SpringFactoryUtil" factory-method="newBean">
  <constructor-arg value="com.liferay.portal.spring.bean.BeanReferenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
 </bean> 
and even if I add this lines ... I'm still not able to use them!